# Изменить i++ на умножения цикл for С++

Tags: c++

Хочу узнать как можно изменить условия i++ на что то другое, например умножения или деления на саму себя, или с другой переменной.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 777; i++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 777; i = i * 2)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: А вот как надо было, спасибо а то я делаю i * 2 и не работает)

Comment: Или коротко -  i *= 2

Comment: @chip, как оно вообще могло заработать, если начальное значение `i` равно нулю :)

Comment: @isnullxbh Это магия)

Comment: @isnullxbh Молодец! Вам +1000 очков.

Comment: @Igor, спасибо :)